# JSZip produces TS2322 error in node.js using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jszip

After adding the import statement:

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
```

The build will produce an error:

```
TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

For these lines of code:

```
const env: string = process.env.NODE_ENV;
...
private timeoutTime: number = process.env.VUE_APP_TIME_OUT; 
...
```

node.js version: 14.16.1

jszip version: 3.7.1

typescript: 3.9.4

Removing the import for JSZip the error goes away.
There are multiple instances of this same error - but not in every case where process.env is used.
Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Are you really using node 6.xx or is this a typo? Node 6 is out of maintenance for more than two years... Maybe it has something to do with that antique node version. You can also try setting `skipLibCheck: true` in the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: oops - that's npm - I'll correct.

Comment: Seem to work for me if I either set `skipLibCheck: true` or install `@types/node`

Comment: @types/node didn't work.

Comment: Neither did the skipLibCheck.

Answer (score 0):

the properties in `process.env` have a type `string | undefined` you have two options

### first

cast them props to yow desired type

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV as string;
```

### second

create a file call `types.d.ts` at yow package.json add a prop call `types` and set the path to yow new file `types.d.ts`

```
{
....
"types":"./types.d.ts",
....
}
```

in yow tsconfig.json there is a prop call `typeRoots` assuming yow `"baseUrl": "./node_modules"`

yow `typesRoots` will look like:

```
//tsconfig.json

{
  "baseUrl": "./node_modules",
  "typeRoots": [
    "../types.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

add this to the new file

```
/// <reference types="node" />

declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
        readonly NODE_ENV: "development" | "production" | "test";
        readonly PUBLIC_URL: string;
        readonly PORT: string;
    }
}
```

Now add all yow vars there all them vars you set there will have a type string

Comment: OK - I wll give this a try.  A couple questions... what is 'yow', and why is this necessary - is JSZip doing something unconventional?

Comment: Followed the steps described and the errors persist.